# Retrieve Ajax star rating value to Asp.net backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This is my rating control in aspx page. When user click the star, i want to update the label3.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Star {
        background-image: url(img/Star.gif);
        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;
    }

    .WaitingStar {
        background-image: url(img/WaitingStar.gif);
        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;
    }

    .FilledStar {
        background-image: url(img/FilledStar.gif);
        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;
    }
</style>
<div>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
                StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star" CurrentRating="2"
                FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar">
            </ajaxToolkit:Rating>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label3"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label4" Text="above"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

I tried out using Rating1.CurrentRating.ToString() but there is nothing on Label3.

```
protected void OnRatingChanged(object sender, RatingEventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = Rating1.CurrentRating.ToString();
    }
```

Is my code wrong or I can get the value in another way? I'm planning to get the value from backend because later I will add it into my database. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-Rating-Control-Example.aspx

Comment: Could you try using e.Value or e.Tag, my friend?

Comment: I think he mentioned that `OnChange()` don't get fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what are you looking for is `OnClick()` not `OnChange()`, as when user click on `Rate` control and change it's rating value you want to get current value of `Rate` control and show it in a label, BTW you should do following below desc,
before doing anything think about the properties of `UpdatePanel` like `UpdateMode` and `ChildrenAsTriggers` that you can set them like `UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` for `UpdatePanel1` if by setting them it still doesnt work do the below steps:

1- Firstly move that label controls into the `ContentTemplate` of `UpdatePanel`
2- Then handle `Click()` event of `ajaxToolkit:Rating`
3- At the end you must have something like in design mode:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
            StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
            FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" OnClick="Rating1_Click">
        </ajaxToolkit:Rating> 
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label3"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label4" Text="above"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the code behind for `Rating1_Click`:

```
protected void Rating1_Click(object sender, RatingEventArgs e)
{
    label3.Text = Rating1.CurrentRating.ToString();
}
```

this works like a charm!!!.